# pip install glove-python-binary not working

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I encountered an error when I am trying to run the code for the GloVe package in Python3.
I'm currently using Windows 10 with Anaconda3. And I'm looking for assistance with this issue.

Here's the code I tried.
`pip install glove-python-binary`

And here's the error message I got.
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement glove-python-binary (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for glove-python-binary`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR1eo.png)

I downgraded Anaconda3's Python version to 3.7, but I encountered a different error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyHS8.png)

Comment: Can you refer to this wiki for guide. Note that, you need to use Python 3.6 and follow the steps mentioned there.. https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/wiki/Installation-on-Windows

Comment: Because I added  a comment to suggest using the magic version of the install commands explicitly, which you ended up trying by not using a symbol, I wanted to clarify that since you are using Anaconda/conda then you should always use the `%conda install` versions of the commands when possible. That is because you opted into making Anaconda your primary package manager by choosing that & so you'll have more robust and portable environments by sticking with that. It seems the package you are interested in isn't represented there and so the fall back to `pip` was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer as I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Firstly, it seems that you're using Jupyter Notebook. Starting a code cell with a bang character, e.g. `!`, instructs Jupyter to treat the code on that line as an OS shell command. For example, `!pip install <package>`.

Secondly, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63728941/13947095) which should solve your problem.

Comment: Usually in modern Jupyter (not the outdated Google Collab fork), automagics is on and so if you run such a command without any symbol in front, it will use the *recommended* magic version of the command. Behind the scenes it will use `%pip install <package>`.  See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install commands added a few years ago to run inside a notebook to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. It is current best practice.

Comment: <continued> The exclamation point in conjunction with install commands can lead to a problem because it doesn't insure the environment is correct. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues and confusion The exclamation point variation can lead to issues in some Jupyter installs. And so it is not be recommended.

Comment: <continued> Those, like the OP, who chose Anaconda/conda as the primary package manager should primarily always try to use the `%conda install` version of the magic install commands for more robust and portable environments. Only resort to the `pip` package manager when encountering cases, such as the one in the OP, for packages not having Anaconada/conda recipes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve it either, but I just found it and am sharing it.

`!pip install glove-python3`
(in colab, after 2023, version:python3.10)

Please refer to https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/issues/120